# Que paquete WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) recomiendan?

Tags: php, wamp

En mi experiencia he utilizado wampserver, easyphp.
Ahora estoy utilizando [laragon](https://laragon.org/) y si estoy contento, sin embargo conocen algun otro paquete que puedan recomendar o valga la pena probar. Debo indicar que la prueba que se quiere realizar es de rendimiento entre los paquetes mencionados y los que puedan aportar.

Saludos

Comment: WAMP es un paquete compuesto por los elementos que comentaste, no existe más de uno solo existe un paquete wamp. Los que mencionas son paquetes de instalación de los mismos y no son recomendables para producción y menos para esperar un buen rendimiento, estos son recomendables para sitios personales e y intranets pequeñas pero principalmente se usan para pruebas en máquinas locales. La más popular a mi parecer es XAMP por lo mismo creo que es la mejor opción ya que encontrarás buena documentación y comentarios del mismo.

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta. La idea no es ponerlos en un servidor en producción pero si instalarlos en las máquinas del equipo de trabajo y escoger la mejor opción para trabajar de mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usbwebserver, a mi me parece excelente por que no es necesario instalarlo, funciona como una aplicación usb, solo la copias en una carpeta, corres el ejecutable y listo, ya tienes un servidor andando.

Adicional php 7 incorpora un servidor integrado, que puedes ejecutar así:

1. Vas a la carpeta donde esta el script de php o la raiz del proyecto php o mvc.
2. Ejecutas:

   php -S localhost:8000

Ahi a tienes un servidor web / php para desarrollo que corres muy rápido (te sirve para desarrollo rápido) por supuesto que debes instalar mysql

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar, agradezco tu respuesta.